# Match Regex from File - PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to set up a PowerShell script to change the date within a file whenever it is run. Below is the current code. It looks for regex with an existing date to replace. I don't know if my regex is correct, but it should check for a date in the format of MM.dd.yy i.e. 10.12.22 for October 12, 2022.

```
$regexDate = '^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$'
$currentDate = Get-Date -UFormat "%m.%d.%y"

Get-Content -path "template1.dat" | % { $_ -Replace $regexDate, $currentDate } |  Out-File "template1.dat"
```

Example input file:

```
Date: 10.12.22

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus. 

Placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis.
```

Comment: Ok.  What is the result?  What is your question?

Comment: Your expression will only match entire strings in the format `yyyy-M-d`.

Comment: When I ran the script with a given input file, it turned the whole file blank. I don’t know what I did wrong. I changed the date format to yyyy-M-d and it also didn’t work.

Comment: Try with regex `'\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b'` if you want to search for dates in format MM.dd.yy

Answer (score 2):

The date format in your file is with 2 digits at the end for the year, instead of 4 digits (also not at the start of the string with the `^` anchor)

```
\b(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\.(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.\d\d\b
```

Or change the `\b` at the end to `$` for the end of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9NB3au/1)

Comment: All of the code is identical except I changed the regex string to: \b(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\.(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.\d\d\b

Still outputs a blank file to template1.dat. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Without regex, what about this ?

```
$pathtofile = "Path to file"
$contenttokeep = Get-Content -LiteralPath $pathtofile | Select-Object -Skip 1

(Get-Date -UFormat "%m.%d.%y") | Out-File -LiteralPath $pathtofile
$contenttokeep | Out-File -LiteralPath $pathtofile -Append
```